# Swiftui DataScannerViewController config guide

Tags: swift, visionkit, datascannerviewcontroller

I'm implementing a DataScannerViewController view but I need to change the user guide view or text.

Can I achieve this with DataScannerViewController or do I have to switch back to Vision and AVFoundation

**Thank You For Your Help**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is an overlay that comes with the view controller that you can use to customize. If you’re talking about changing the text that Apple provides to “slow down” and hints like that, then you might be out of luck.